# How to close currently running serial port using c#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, com-port

Let’s say currently COMPORT2 is running and in used.

How can I create a console app that will dispose this existing serial port and will allow to reopen the port again?

Comment: What do you mean by "dispose"? Do you want to kick another application off of the port?

Comment: Yes, and I want to reopen for another use. I tried closing after I open but somehow it’s still holding on and can not access

Comment: You shouldn't write a separate application to fix a problem in the first application. Show the [mre] of your code that uses but doesn't properly free the port. Do you `Dispose()` all relevant objects?

Comment: The problem now is, the moment I connect the serial port, it’s already busy. Error message is “Access to COMPORT is denied” that’s why I wondering if I can create a separate file to do so

Comment: That is probably because the previous instance of your application is still running and holding on to it. You should fix that problem, not the problem it results in.

Comment: please post the code that shows the opening and **closing** of the serial port. sometimes an exception can bypass the closing code and an application is closed while the port remains opened